# Image does not display in expo IOS build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

my image works displays on android build (aab,apk), expo go on both android,ios and ios simulator but not on iphone builds

```
  <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/icons/back.png")}
        style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}
      />
```